# ssl certificate warning IOS 8.1.2 and safari

Tags: ios, iphone, ssl, ssl-certificate, mobile-safari

I have a Comodo Domain Control Validated certificate from namecheap.com
According to namecheap customer support & ssl labs (http://bit.ly/1JYODhn) I have installed this certificate properly.

**My problem is:** The certificate throws a warning on Iphone 5 (ios - 7 & 8 and safari 7) . It should be noted the warning is not thrown on Desktops, or Iphone 6.

**I have already** verified my SSL Certificate Chain and there are no problems there. namecheap.com recommends I add my root certificate to the chain, I am not so sure of this since ssl labs says this is a problem.

**Anyone know** what setting IOS is so sensitive to in SSL installations?

**Error from Apache Logs:**
[Tue Apr 21 15:32:54 2015] [debug] ssl_engine_kernel.c(1924): OpenSSL: Exit: error in SSLv3 read client hello C

Comment: "The certificate throws a warning " - and the warning would be what?

Comment: Certificate for this server is invalid

Comment: The certificate looks good except that it includes the root certificate. There will be a problem if the browser does not support SNI because then it gets a different certificate, but modern browsers should support SNI. Do you get this error all the time, i.e. in WLAN and mobile network?

Comment: Hi Stefan thanks for the reply. I only get this warning on Iphone and both on Wlan and network.

Comment: I dont get this warning on IPad

Comment: no problem detected here https://www.sslshopper.com/ssl-checker.html#hostname=hoergeraeteberatung-anfordern.de

Comment: I thought maybe the problem had to do with IPhone not trusting 'AddTrust External CA Root'.  But namecheap.com said this is not a problem.

Comment: Have you checked the time on the device? Maybe the time is wrong and the   new certificate is not yet valid.

Comment: Its actually not a new certificate. I will investigate SNI support on older Iphones and see what I can do to offer more for these devices.

Comment: Seems like SNI support for Iphones is sufficiently there  http://www.browserstack.com/screenshots/377fa87b4c3fec55be2953d06a100fc5ee8e5294